# C# Копирование массива

Tags: c#, массивы, циклы

Добрый день.
Осваиваю язык C#. Задача в следующем. Как скопировать последовательно элементы двумерного массива размером 5*5 в два массива размером 5*2 и 5*3 . Используя только цикл for и if.

Буду весьма благодарен)

---

Начал с создания трех массивов:

```
int[,] arr1 = new int[5, 5];
int[,] arr2 = new int[5, 2];
int[,] arr3 = new int[5, 5];
```

далее, создал цикл в цикле, так как это двумерный массив:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < arr1.Length; k++)
    {
        arr2[i, k] = arr1[i, k];
        arr3[i, k] = arr1[i, k+2];
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(arr3);
```

А вот саму тонкость вывода, нащупать не могу

Comment: Если мы напишем готовое решение, то вы язык не освоите. Напишите как вы пробовали решить задачу и что конкретно не получилось.

Comment: Понял)
Начал с создания трех массивов

            int[,] arr1 = new int[5, 5];
            int[,] arr2 = new int[5, 2];
            int[,] arr3 = new int[5, 5];

далее, создал цикл в цикле, так как это двумерный массив:

            for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < arr1.Length; k++)
                {
                    arr2[i, k] = arr1[i, k];
                    arr3[i, k] = arr1[i, k+2];
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(arr3);
            }

А вот саму тонкость вывода, нащупать не могу

Comment: @GraphicalDesign допишите это в вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: Возможно вам нужна функция Array.Copy,  она упрощает жизнь, ею можно заменить цикл копирования.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [`Array.Length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.array.length(v=vs.110).aspx) возвращает:

   > Общее число элементов во всех измерениях массива

   Сомневаюсь, что именно это вам нужно. Храните размерности массива в константах/переменных или воспользуйтесь методом [`Array.GetLength(int dimension)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.array.getlength(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. Так как все массивы имеют разные размерности, сомневаюсь что можно реализовать задуманное внутри одного и того же цикла. Подумайте об этом.
3. `Console.WriteLine(...)` не умеет выводить кастомные типы и не обязан уметь, он просто вызовет метод `.ToString()` на переданном объекте. Сомневаюсь, что это именно то что вам нужно. Организуйте вывод в цикле, добавляя вручную в нужных местах вывод разделителей между элементами в строке и переводы строк между строками элементов.

Answer (score 4):

Заработало) вот как выглядит)
Спасибо кто помог.

```
int[,] arr = new int[5, 5]
{
    { 1, 4, 5, 5, 5 },
    { 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 },
    { 3, 6, 3, 1, 6 },
    { 1, 4, 7, 9, 9 },
    { 4, 5, 5, 5, 5 }
};


int[,] arr1 = new int[5, 2];
int[,] arr2 = new int[5, 3];


for (int i = 0; i< 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j< 2; j++)
    {
        arr1[i, j] = arr[i, j];
        Console.Write(arr1[i, j]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}


for (int i1 = 0; i1< 5; i1++)
{
    for (int j1 = 0; j1< 3; j1++)
    {
        arr2[i1, j1] = arr[i1, j1 + 2];
        Console.Write(arr2[i1, j1]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```